# How to calculate the logLik of a linear model acquired through matrix operations

Tags: r, linear-model, likelihood

If you were to run a linear model with the `lm` function, it is easy to obtain the log liklihood of the fit with the following:

```
lm1 <- lm(response ~ explanatory, weights=optional)
logLik(lm1)
```

However, how would one calculate the log likelihood of a model fit through matrix operations? As there seems to be no defined method in `logLik` for this.

```
x <- explanatory
y <- response
sigi <- diag(weights)
xtxi <- solve(t(x) %*% sigi %*% x)
beta2 <- xtxi %*% t(x) %*% sigi %*% y 
res <- y - x %*% beta2 #Residuals
sig <- sqrt(sum(res^2)/nrow(x)-1) 
s.e <- as.matrix(sqrt(diag(xtxi))*sig) #Standard eror of beta coeffs
```

"To assessing the overall quality of the model, We can look at the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) and Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC). These can be used to compare the performance of different models for a given set of data."

```
> AIC(fit)
[1] 263.8177
> BIC(fit)
[1] 271.6332
> logLik(fit)
'log Lik.' -128.9088 (df=3)
```

Source: https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-model-by-maximum-likelihood/

One of my aims is compare multiple models of the same data and need the `logLik` or eqv of the model fit through matrix operations.

Comment: Well you have or can calculate all of the parameters of the likelihood function, and a ready way to verify your results.

Comment: Study the [code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/logLik.R#L70). It's pretty simple.

Comment: @generic_user, I believe you are referring to the AIC and BIC in the initial question, these are citation examples from the hyperlink in original post. @Roland, thanks for your reply also, I did come across this earlier, but this (to me at least) doesn't make it clear, how one would go about calculating the `logLik` in the proposed scenario. I apologise if I'm missing something quite apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple hours I have realised, @Roland was correct, it is a pretty simple answer:

```
ssr <- sum(res^2) #sum of squared residuals
logL <- -(nrow(x)/2)*(log(ssr/nrow(x)))-(nrow(x)/2)*(log(2*pi))-(nrow(x)/2)
```

where `nrow(x)` is the number of observations. Tested this with a normal `lm` and it matches the `logLik` output. Citations: see @Rolands link to the source code.